# Write a query to show the staff in STAFF table that have left. Show all columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query to show the staff in STAFF table that have left. Show all columns

when i try to find a staff in my staff table that have left it coming up with error

any help would be helpful

SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE IN dateleft;

i expect the code will show me staff that have left not who currently there

Comment: `SELECT * FROM staff` ?

Comment: I dont want every record i only want to show the record that a staff have left not every single record

Comment: Make inner join to your table with records? Your question is still unclear.

Comment: Your question is being down voted because you didn't share the definition of your table, making it impossible for anyone to actually answer your question

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM staff
WHERE dateleft IS NOT NULL; i solved my own answer taken me a good while to think of the answer my self

Comment: As you didn't post the data structure or sample data it was highly unlikely that any of us would have come up with the solution. Fortunately the lessons you teach yourself are the most valuable.